# Drawing a bisecting diagonal line in canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

http://jsfiddle.net/skq3qfze/

HTML:

```
(canvas class="col-md-1 myCanvas")(/canvas)
```

CSS:

```
.myCanvas {
        height: 400px;
        width: 400px;
        border: 1px solid black;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var canvas = $('.myCanvas');
        var context = canvas.get(0).getContext('2d');

        var height = canvas.height();
        var width = canvas.width();


        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(0,0);
        context.lineTo(width, height);
        context.stroke();
});
```

As you can see, it doesn't seem to actually create a diagonal line stretching from corner to corner. What would the correct arguments be to properly bisect the square?

Answer (score 0):

When you use CSS to format a canvas, the internal coordinate system of the canvas doesn't change. `canvas.width` and `canvas.height` stay as they are. What does change is the output of the canvas in the HTML document. The canvas gets stretched in one axis and and cropped in the other which is the result you see here.

When you want a canvas of 400px by 400px, put the `width` and `height` into the `<canvas>` tag and not into the CSS classes:

HTML:

```
<canvas class="myCanvas" width=400 height=400></canvas>
```

CSS:

```
.myCanvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```